# What is the smallest voltage that an Arduino UNO can read from the analogRead()?

Tags: arduino

Is there a source that I can find for the kind of Arduino.

Comment: like with most ADC's, it's V_ref / 2^{number of bits}.

Comment: What is V_ref / 2^{number of bits} ? Sorry I am a beginner.

Comment: Why not read the Arduino API reference page for AnalogRead?

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogread/

Comment: I visited the website, and it sounds confusing as a beginner for me to understand.

Comment: Ask about what you don't understand. Not just the answer. What are you going to do with it if you don't understand it? The answer is in that link: `5V / (2^10)`

Comment: I can see that it is 0.0049 volts. But I don't understand what is the significance or what it refers to? I am completely lost.

Comment: The website specifically has an example what the voltage is on the UNO.

Comment: I'd assume the sammelst voltage you can measure is of course 0.00V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Arduino ADC has a bit resolution of

Vreference / (2 ^ ADC_bits)

ADC bits are usually 10
2^10 = 1024, so
bit resolution is Vreference/ 1024

Arduino **default** Vref is set to the supply voltage, Vcc.
For an Arduino using the default Vref the resolution is

- 5/1024 = 4.88 mV/bit for a 5V Vcc Arduino
- 3.3V/1024 = 2.93 mV  for a 3.3V cc Arduino

Note well that this is the resolution -  the apparent voltage step between readings.
The accuracy may well be rather worse in many cases.

Depending on the processor used the Vref value may be able to be set to voltages other than Vcc.
The table below explains the options available by Arduino type, and the ling is to the page where that information came from, which also provides related information.

**________________________________________**

**What is the Reference Voltage?**

See [here](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogreference/) for technical details.

Set using the : analogReference() function

From the above link:

Description: Configures the reference voltage used for analog input (i.e. the value used as the top of the input range). The options are:

**Arduino AVR Boards (Uno, Mega, Leonardo, etc.)**

DEFAULT: the default analog reference of 5 volts (on 5V Arduino boards) or 3.3 volts (on 3.3V Arduino boards)

INTERNAL: an built-in reference, equal to 1.1 volts on the ATmega168 or ATmega328P and 2.56 volts on the ATmega32U4 and ATmega8 (not available on the Arduino Mega)

INTERNAL1V1: a built-in 1.1V reference (Arduino Mega only)

INTERNAL2V56: a built-in 2.56V reference (Arduino Mega only)

EXTERNAL: the voltage applied to the AREF pin (0 to 5V only) is used as the reference.

**Arduino SAMD Boards (Zero, etc.)**

AR_DEFAULT: the default analog reference of 3.3V

AR_INTERNAL: a built-in 2.23V reference

AR_INTERNAL1V0: a built-in 1.0V reference

AR_INTERNAL1V65: a built-in 1.65V reference

AR_INTERNAL2V23: a built-in 2.23V reference

AR_EXTERNAL: the voltage applied to the AREF pin is used as the reference

**Arduino megaAVR Boards (Uno WiFi Rev2)**

DEFAULT: a built-in 0.55V reference

INTERNAL: a built-in 0.55V reference

VDD: Vdd of the ATmega4809. 5V on the Uno WiFi Rev2

INTERNAL0V55: a built-in 0.55V reference

INTERNAL1V1: a built-in 1.1V reference

INTERNAL1V5: a built-in 1.5V reference

INTERNAL2V5: a built-in 2.5V reference

INTERNAL4V3: a built-in 4.3V reference

EXTERNAL: the voltage applied to the AREF pin (0 to 5V only) is used as the reference

**Arduino SAM Boards (Due)**

AR_DEFAULT: the default analog reference of 3.3V. This is the only supported option for the Due.

The default reference voltage is the power supply - 5V or 3V3 depending on the Vcc voltage of the processor used.

In addition SOME processor versions can have other lower reference voltages.

Comment: Nice copy pasta. How in earth does OP understand this, but not the link he posted as comment.

Comment: @Swedgin The portion above the 1st line is not copy pasted and wholly answers the question. The material below the line was indeed initially copy and pasted (obviously) but had enough formating done to improve its utility usefully :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's a 10 bit ADC, so splits the input range into 1024 levels, or roughly 1000 as that makes the sums easier.

Depending on whether you have a 5 V or a 3.3 V MCU, the resolution will be about 5 mV or 3.3 mV.

Whether the resolution, that is the smallest step we can resolve, relates to the *smallest voltage we can measure* is another matter. I did some experiments recently to see how well my Trinket M0 (another MCU that can be used with the Arduino project, using ATSAMD21E18) measured close to ground, and it didn't read for the first few steps, and then had some hysteresis so read differently whether the input voltage was going up or down. This was not entirely unexpected, what was impressive was that it read as well as it did very close to ground.

You ought to do the same experiment with your MCU, to see whether it will actually read 3 mV differently to 6 mV, or whether you need to get above a threshold before the ADC starts working properly.

Comment: How do we derive 3.3mv? Does it mean the smallest voltage is 3.3 mv?

Comment: The ADC (ie ardunio) is powered from 3.3V  and thus the resolution of one lsb is V/2^bits = 3.3/2^10  ~ 3.3/1000 ~ 3.3mV  ( it would be closer to 3.22mV but as a quick calc its good enough)

Comment: @JonRB and kkksrct The UNO is not powered from 3.3V, so the smallest voltage is not 3.3mV. Let me quote the AnalogRead page if it is not obvious : "On an Arduino UNO, for example, this yields a resolution between readings of: 5 volts / 1024 units or, 0.0049 volts (4.9 mV) per unit".

Comment: @justme not always. https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogreference/

Comment: @JonRB True, which is why it is explained in the next sentence right after my quoted sentence on the AnalogRead page. Reference can be changed but default is still 5V.